# Explain the overridden method of equal in String class

Tags: java, string

In String class overridden method `equal` use the `count`, `value` and `offset`. What are they, **Why we are not using very simple like for count, we can use length() function**, value which is array we can use `toCharArray();` and for offset we can take length()-1. I tried to search those keywords count, value and offset in Java Documentation but not found....

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: did you look at other code placeses in String class,in my opinon value is char array which store String as a char arr , offset is index of this char arr and to string it just iterating on the characters and checking equals or not ,count means lenght of string ,you also asking why used like this  I think using like that better performance from lenght() method using

Comment: "we can use toCharArray()" - do you *really* want to have to create a new array every time you compare strings? That sounds like a really, really bad idea to me.

Comment: Could you link to the implementation you're looking at, please? It changed a lot around Java 7 update 6, IIRC. Your expectation of just using `length()-1` is incorrect, I suspect... but it's hard to say for sure without knowing which implementation you're looking at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the definitions:

```
value  -> array of char holding the chars present in the String
count  -> number of chars in the String
offset -> offset of first character to be considered in the value array
```

For example, consider the array

```
char[] chars = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
String str = new String(chars, 1, 2);
System.out.println(str);   // Prints bc  

char[] chars2 = new char[]{'b', 'c'};
String str2 = new String(chars2, 0, 2);
System.out.println(str2);   // Prints bc

System.out.println(str.equals(str2));  // Prints true
```

You can imagine that value is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` for the `String` `str` and `['b', 'c']` for the `String` `str2`.

This is not true. Both strings internally use an array of chars of size 2, the array `['b', 'c']`.

But when you ask for a `substring` it creates a new `String`, with the same `value` and different values of `offset` and `count`.

---

Here a description of `value`, `offset`, `count` with some example

```
command                             value           count  offset   toString
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
String str = new String("ABC");     ['A', 'B', 'C']   3      0       ABC
str.substring(2);                   ['A', 'B', 'C']   1      2       C    
str.substring(1, 2);                ['A', 'B', 'C']   2      1       BC
```

Comment: thanks for nice explanation, If my question is correct plz upvote it....

Answer (score 1):

From `JDK 1.8.0_65` -> `java.lang` package -> `String.java` class :

```
/**
 * Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
 * true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
 * String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
 * object.
 *
 * @param  anObject
 *         The object to compare this {@code String} against
 *
 * @return  {@code true} if the given object represents a {@code String}
 *          equivalent to this string, {@code false} otherwise
 *
 * @see  #compareTo(String)
 * @see  #equalsIgnoreCase(String)
 */
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

where `value` is defined as

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];
```

So I hope that pretty much answers your doubt.

Comment: I don't understand in what this answer helps to understand what are count and offset.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO the documentation itself explains the *overridden method of equal in String class* the `count` and `offset` are `value.length` and `0` respectively.

Comment: The confusion here is caused by OP not specifying the Java version. Specifically the internal implementation of `String` has changed, OP had an old version, this answer refers to a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

The `offset` and `count` fields are used, because the `String` compared may be a substring of another `String`. In this case no new `String` object is created but the string points to a location within another `String`. Thats why the `count` and `offset` fields exist.

Example:

```
String s1 = "DoTheHuzzle";
String s2 = s1.subString(2, 5);   // "The"
```

In this case `s2` has an `offset` of 2 and a `length` of 3.

Comment: At least, that used to be true. I don't believe it is these days, which is why I asked the OP to refer to a specfic version.